# How to render a Server array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, encoding

In an MVC applicaiton, I should compare between a Javascript array and an array from the server. When I'm trying to render the server array in the Javascript code, I'm getting the following wrongly encoded result:

How to get rid of the encoding string (`&quot`)??

```
function checkCorrectness() {
    var data = [&quot;Item 1&quot;,&quot;item 2&quot;,&quot;item 3&quot;,&quot;item 4&quot;];
}
```

Comment: what is a server array?  you're striping servers?

Comment: And just how are you rendering that array? Have you tried JSON encoding the the array as a string and then using something like HtmlHelper.Raw? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740(v=vs.108).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Replace all `&quot;` with `"` [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d66U9/)

```
"[&quot;Item 1&quot;,&quot;item 2&quot;,&quot;item 3&quot;,&quot;item 4&quot;];".replace(/\&quot;/gi,'"');
```

Comment: Is this the best solution? Cannot I render the array without the encoding?

Comment: @Homam you can if you use innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Convert the server response object to the JSON and give a try